# Как пользоваться обфускацией кода в Android

Tags: android, обфускация

Решил заняться защитой приложения, в gradle файле обнаружил, что у меня уже стоит proguard:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Я нашел расположение этих файлов по пути:

1. StudioProjects/MyApp/app/proguard-rules.pro
2. Android/SDK/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt

Внутри текстового файла указано, что с 2.2 gradle этот файл не используется:

```
# This file is no longer maintained and is not used by new (2.2+) versions of the
# Android plugin for Gradle. Instead, the Android plugin for Gradle generates the
# default rules at build time and stores them in the build directory.
```

Я ничего не нашел в директории своего проекта. А файл pro, который находится в проекте, не подходит для play console (требуется txt или map, map я тоже не нашел)
В связи с этим 2 вопроса:

1. Где находится файл txt для деобфускации, если в proguard-android-optimize.txt указано, что тот не используется, но его нет, в build так же пусто
2. Стоит ли рассчитывать на защиту proguard, если в приложении есть ключи доступа к БД?

Comment: бд локальная или на сервере?

Comment: @Andrew на сервере

Comment: если это обычный access_token то он тухнет чаще всего через некоторое время, и токен уже по-умолчанию зашифрован :)

Comment: @Andrew, вряд ли автор собрался зашивать в APK протухающие токены. Скорее речь идёт о secret key или подобном постоянном ключе, про который пишут: надёжно спрячьте и при этом требуют его в каждом запросе к API.

Comment: @woesss, тогда про токен не в тему)) просто допустил и решил уточнить :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Разве в справке консоли не написано где его искать? - при стандартной структуре проекта где-то там:
   `"ВашПроэкт/app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt"`
   Но его там может не быть пока вы не выполните сборку приложения c включенной обфускацией:
   `minifyEnabled true`
   Вы должны скопировать его сразу после сборки релиза для публикации, потому что при каждой сборке он может измениться и расшировка логов с mapping другой версии будет не правильной

Подробнее в гайде: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

2. Нет, не стоит - он не шифрует строки, ресурсы и другие данные, только переименовывает классы, поля, методы и вырезает то, что не требуется для выполнения кода.

Comment: В том и дело, что в папке проекта в пути /app/build/outputs есть только 2 папки: apk и logs, при этом minifyEnabled true. Может быть, проблема в том, что я компилирую не apk, a aab? По гайду я уже смотрел инструкции, но файла я так и не нашел

Comment: После включения `minifyEnabled true` синхронизацию делали? Сборку aab делали после синхронизации? Очистку проекта делать пробовали (`Build->Clean Project`)? Ищете в том проекте, модуле, который компилируете? Если ищете через встроенный в студию проводник - попробуйте обновить:  File->Reload All from Disk (ctrl+alt+Y). Иногда так же требуется закрыть/открыть проект, чтобы сбросить некий глюк IDE